# The column cannot be modified. [ Column name = UserId ]

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-ce

I'm relatively new to MVC and SQL CE, and I seem to be having a problem with my primary key field. Inside my database I have 'User' table, and that table has a primary key called 'UserId'. I've created a registration page which gets some data from and should then store that data in the database. However, when the form submit button is clicked, the following error is detected:

```
The column cannot be modified. [ Column name = UserId ]
```

This is weird because i'm not attempting to UserId value. The code below is my post action for the registration action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Registration(UserModel user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (var db = new BlogDbContext())
            {
                var crypto = new SimpleCrypto.PBKDF2();

                var encryptPassword = crypto.Compute(user.Password);

                var newUser = db.Users.Create();

                newUser.Username = user.Username;
                newUser.FirstName = user.FirstName;
                newUser.LastName = user.LastName;
                newUser.Email = user.Email;
                newUser.Password = encryptPassword;
                newUser.PasswordSalt = crypto.Salt;
                newUser.JoinDate = DateTime.Now;

                db.Users.Add(newUser);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "User");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Registration Failure");
        }

        return View();
    }
```

When I originally created the database using SQL CE in VS 2012, I set the identity option to 'true' believing that this would auto-increment the primary key column. I've looked on SO for similar questions, however, the majority see to include some sort of SQL query, which I haven't delved into yet. Any help will be greatly appreciated.